# Shows " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') " when try to read data from a state passed as props using strapi DB

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, vite, strapi

I created two states and passed from context.tsx:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const Context = createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{ categories, setCategories, products, setProducts }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppContext;
```

Then I de-structured it in my home.tsx page:

```
import Category from "./category/category";
import Products from "../products/products";
import Banner from "./banner";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "../../utils/api";
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../utils/context";

export default function Home() {
  const { categories, setCategories, products, setProducts } =
    useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
    getCatregories();
  }, []);

  const getProducts = () => {
    fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*").then((res) => {
      setProducts(res);
      console.log(products);
    });
  };

  const getCatregories = () => {
    fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*").then((res) => {
      setCategories(res);
      console.log(categories);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Banner />
      <Category categories={categories} />
      <Products
        products={products}
        innerPage={false}
        heading={"Poppular Products"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I tried mapping through it in my category component:

```
export default function Category({ categories }) {
  if (!categories) {
    return null; // or a loading spinner or error message
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 p-4 mx-auto xl:grid xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-4 xl:p-[80px] xl:w-[90%] ">
        {categories.data.map((item) => {
          <div key={item.id} className="overflow-hidden">
            <img
              className="hover:scale-125 hover:brightness-50 transition ease-in-out 300ms"
              src={
                import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_DEV_URL +
                item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url
              }
              alt=""
            />
          </div>;
        })}
        ;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it shows error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

and also:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

if I use undefined check for the mapping.

`{ categories?.data.map((item) }`

Comment: Are you sure that the error isn't here? `item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url`

Comment: yes! it shows in the console that the 5th line i.e `{categories.data.map((item) => {` has the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `categories` is meant to be an object with `data` property, why do you initialise it as an array?

This is the source of your problem. Before data is retrieved, you're trying to access `[].data` which is `undefined`.

Looking at your usage, I would either init it as an object representing the intended format...

```js
const [categories, setCategories] = useState({ data: [] });
```

**OR**

More practically, unnest the `data` property and just keep the array

```js
const getCatregories = async () => {
  // unnest the `data` array
  setCategories((await fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*")).data);
};
```

From there you'd use `categories.map(...)` when rendering.

---

Do not use both options here. I'd preference the second one as it keeps your state data cleaner.

Comment: here after the changes if i use `categories.map(. . .)` it says `Uncaught TypeError: categories.map is not a function.`

and if i use `categories.data.map(. . .)`  it works but i tried console logging my data it says data array is empty but correctly shows data being passed in my react-dev-tools

Comment: @Praroop please tell me you didn't use both of the code snippets in my answer

Comment: no no @Phil when i used you first snippet, it is not showing that error anymore but when i try console logging that state it shows `{data: Array(0)` . i cant understand, is it not assigning the api fetched data correctly to the object?

Comment: You are using console.log just after updating state, it will show the old value. Move your console.logs to the body of the component

Comment: @Praroop or just don't use `console.log()` for debugging. I will harp on about this forever but the console is for logging; if you want to debug, use a debugger. But even before that, just try using your data and code. Why does everyone feel the need to log things before they even try using them?

Comment: thanks a lot Konrad and Phil it solved my error and it help me a lot!